# How can I fully automate Windows Bluetooth Pairing and Unpairing?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bonding

For purposes of building an automated hardware test rig, I need to be able to automatically pair and unpair a bluetooth device with a windows machine. Windows API's require user confirmation for security reasons.

Is there any way to fully automate this one the test rigs? It would be acceptable to turn off security policies, etc.

Problematic Prompt 1:
[image]

Problematic Prompt 2:
[image]

Comment: In fact Windows API does not require user confirmation. You can use Bluetooth Framework for your test apps.

Comment: I've added some example prompts to show what I'm talking about. So far, I find that Windows DOES require user confirmation.

Comment: No, it does not if you do all correctly. Of course if you call pairng from your code, not from Windows Add Device dialog.

Comment: Can you pont me towards examples for "correctly"?

Comment: Try BluetoothMabager demo from Bluetooth Framework package (https://www.btframework.com/bluetoothframework.htm).